# what is the difference between using training=True or not in tf.layers.batch_normalization(training=?)

Tags: python, tensorflow, batch-processing, normalization

Recently, I made an experiment about using: `tf.layers.batch_normalization(input, training=True)` and `using tf.layers.batch_normalization(input)`, both of two situations are all in training period.

But some strange things happened. If I use: `tf.layers.batch_normalization(input, training=True)`, the `tfevent file` created by `tf.summary` is about 400MB, but if I use `tf.layers.batch_normalization(input)`, that file is just about 20MB, I can not understand the reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](http://ruishu.io/2016/12/27/batchnorm/) batch normalization has distinct behaviors during training verus test time:

During testing phase, you normalize layer activations according to mini-batch statistics, while in testing you do it according to estimated population statistics.

This behaviour is controlled through the `training` parameter, as explained in [TensorFlow's documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization).

Thus, during testing, much little information is stored. You shouldn't set it that way for training purposes though.

Hope this helped!